# If $\tau$ is weakly continuous and $(Z_n)$ is a sequence with limit point $Z$ on $L^1$ and $Z_n\le Y$, then $Z\le Y$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space and $\tau:L^1(\operatorname P)\to L^1(\operatorname P)$ be linear and continuous with respect to the weak topology on $L^1(\operatorname P)$. Let $Z\in L^1(\operatorname P)$ be a limit point of $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq L^1(\operatorname P)$ with respect to the weak topology on $L^1(\operatorname P)$ and assume that $$\tau Z_n\le\frac Xn+Y\tag2$$ for some $X,Y\in L^1(\operatorname P)$.

> Why can we conclude that $\tau Z\le Y$?

The continuity assumption should be equivalent to $$\operatorname E[\tau(U_n)V]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\operatorname E[\tau(U)V]\;\;\;\text{for all }V\in L^\infty(\operatorname P)\cong L^1(\operatorname P)'\tag2$$ for all $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq L^1(\operatorname P)$ and $U\in L^1(\operatorname P)$ with $\operatorname E[U_nV]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\operatorname E[UV]$ for all $V\in L^\infty(\operatorname P)$, if I'm getting things right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that we do not have that $\tau Z \leq Y$ a.e. Then there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ and a set $A$ of positive measure such that $\tau Z \geq Y + \varepsilon$ on $A$ (by writing $\{\tau Z > Y\}$ as the countable union of the sets $\{ \tau Z \geq Y + n^{-1}\}$).

We can pass to a subnet $(Z_\lambda)$ of the sequence $Z_n$ to assume that $Z_\lambda \to Z$ in the weak sense as a net. This means that for any $V \in L^\infty$, we have $E[ Z_\lambda V] \to E[Z V]$. By taking $V = 1_A$, we can then write
$$\int_A Y d\mathbb{P} + \varepsilon \mathbb{P}(A) \leq \int_A \tau Z d\mathbb{P} = \lim_{\lambda} \int_A \tau Z_\lambda d\mathbb{P} \leq \lim_{\lambda} \int_A \frac{X}{\lambda} + Y d\mathbb{P} = \int_A Y d \mathbb{P}$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: As you may have guessed, the $\tau$ I'm interested in is given by $\tau f:=f\circ\theta$, where $\theta$ is a measure-preserving map on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$. If $\theta$ is invertible, it's easy for me to show that $\tau$ is continuous wrt the weak topology. But otherwise I'm struggling to see why it is true. Do you have an idea? I guess it's obvious.

Comment: BTW: It should be $\frac X\lambda$ on the right-hand side of your last inequality. And I guess you're using dominated convergence for the last equality.

Comment: Dominated convergence is unnecessary. $\int_A X$ is a finite constant and $(\frac{1}{\lambda})$ is a net converging to $0$.

Comment: For your first comment, notice that in this answer we only use that if $Z_n \to Z$ weakly then $E[\tau(Z_n) V] \to E[\tau(Z) V]$ for $V$ the indicator function of a measurable set. This property is weaker than weak convergence and hence easier to verify. It will clearly suffice to see that there is a $W \in L^\infty$ such that $V = W \circ \theta$ a.e. for such a $V$.This is straightforward since if $V = 1_A$ then $W = 1_{\Theta(A)}$ will do.

Comment: Regarding the DCT: You're right. that was nonsensical. I'm still a bit confused about the net convergence thing, since I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: And regarding the other thing: Since measurable functions with finite range (i.e. "simple" measurable functions) are dense in $L^\infty$, wouldn't your claim immediately yield the weak continuity? In any case, aren't you using that $\omega\in A\Leftrightarrow\theta(\omega)\in\theta(A)$? This doesn't need to hold, if $\theta$ is not injective.

Comment: ah shoot you are right. My idea doesn't work. To avoid a messy comment thread, I'm going to post a response to the first part of the comment in [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107228/discussion-between-rhys-steele-and-0xbadf00d)

Comment: Wait, I think I've just been missing the obvious. In the setting you are interested in $\tau$ is an isometry. But it is a general fact that strong-strong continuous operators are also weak-weak continuous. Indeed, an early exercise about the weak topology is to show that if $S$ is a topological space and $f: S \to X$ then $f$ is continuous iff $\phi \circ f$ is continuous for all $\phi \in X^*$. In our case, since $\tau$ is bounded and linear, $\phi \circ \tau \in (L^1)^*$ for all $\phi \in (L^1)*$ and so in particular is continuous.